# UITableView ignoring registering a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What happens, when I ignore to register a given cell for my `UITableView` but then call `dequeueReusableCell` in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` later?

The call looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: kIdentifier) as? MyCellType

    if cell.isNil {
        cell = MyCellType(withIdentifier: kIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Apparently it seems to automatically register the new cell. Is this assumption correct?

The reason why I can just call `tableView.register(MyCellType.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kIdentifier) has legacy reasons, where registering the cell like this will mess up the layout of the cell, whereas initializing correctly with`MyCellType(...)` won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.
I often write this style code in Object-C, is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check empty cell as below :

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = MyCellType(withIdentifier: kIdentifier)
   }
```

Comment: I already have that check. Or why shouldn't I be using `cell.isNil`?

Comment: then what issue occurs ?

Comment: did you use prototypecell or xib ?

Comment: I am just wondering, if the `dequeue` works, even if I don't register the cell before. Prototypecell.

Comment: if you are used prototypecell then you dont need the register cell in viewdidload .if your are  used cell through xib then you need to register cell.